# Android support-v7-appcompat issue with 4.0 & above

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat, android-appcompat

I am backporting my Android application to support older devices (2.3.3+). Previously, it was 4.0+.

I am using ActionBar and doing custom styling on it in code in the base class. After conversion to Support ActionBar, the styling code is:

```
public static void styleActionBar(final ActionBarActivity activity) {
    /* Setup the actionbar as required */
    final ActionBar actionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();

    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xfffffff));
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.customview_actionbar);

        ....
    }
}
```

After this change, all things work perfectly on 2.3.3. But, for 4.0+, it crashes at the line

```
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xfffffff));
```

Also, if I comment this line out, I can see that it crashes at `actionBar.setCustomView` also.

Stack trace on 4.2:

```
....
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplICS.setBackgroundDrawable(ActionBarImplICS.java:176)
    at com.mycompany.myproj.ProjBaseActivity.styleActionBar(ProjBaseActivity.java:68)
    at com.mycompany.myproj.ProjBaseActivity.onCreate(ProjBaseActivity.java:32)
    at com.mycompany.myproj.TextSearchActivity.onCreate(TextSearchActivity.java:60)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
```

It works perfectly in 2.3.3 & it looks to me like an issue in support-v7-appcompat.

Any clues / help on overcoming or working around ? Thanks in advance.

Edit 1: `values-v14/styles.xml` content:

```
<resources>

  <style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/proj_theme_color</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: When exactly are you calling that method?

Comment: in `onCreate()` of the activity just after `super.onCreate()`

Comment: Sorry about the previous question, it was obvious from the stacktrace. Do you have different themes per API level(`values-v14` etc)? Some themes don't have an `ActionBar`(like dialog based themes).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AppCompat v7 you need to call SupportActionBar instead of ActionBar

```
 final **SupportActionBar** actionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();

if (actionBar != null) {
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xfffffff));
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.customview_actionbar);
```